# Cast NSObject to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting

I'm developing an iPhone application with latest SDK.

I have this code:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSObject* response =
        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData
                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error:&error];

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSDictionary* resp = [response objectAtIndex:0];
```

This line, `NSDictionary* resp = [response objectAtIndex:0];` doesn't work. I get this compilation time error: `No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'`.

I could do something like this:

`NSArray* array = [NSArray initWithArray:response];` but I think it will create two objects and it will waste resources. 
**How do I cast a NSObject to NSArray?**

Comment: There is no reason why your code shouldn't work.

Comment: This is the reason: No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'

Comment: Please, stop downvoting. It's a good question that really doesn't work.

Comment: What Kind of class is your response? Trye `NSLog(@"%@", [response class])'. If it is not an array you will not be able to cast it.

Comment: I can't speak for the other down voters, but you earned mine when I asked what you've tried to fix the problem your self and you said "Nothing. I don't know how do to it." With over 4000 rep you should know by now that this isn't how SO works.

Comment: @VansFannel there are 2 answers already, what else do you need?

Comment: if your `response` can represent different classes use `id` as type not `NSObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com.es/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html) explains why I must use `id response =` instead of `NSObject* response =`.

If I use `id` I can send any message to `response` object.

So, If I have checked if `[response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]` there won't be any problem if I do `[response objectAtIndex:0]`.

And also, it won't be any compilation time error.

I've added this answer because there will be more people with the same problem.

Comment: This is really the correct answer. If you don't know the type of an object, just don't give it a static type! Declaring it as an `NSObject *` is misleading the type checker into thinking that you mean to treat the variable as an NSObject when you actually mean to treat it as something more specific, which is why you get spurious errors.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSObject* response =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData
                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:&error];

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray*)response;
        NSDictionary* resp = [responseArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Casting and then checking?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Although, is it by definition wrong to cast first and check after? Since it wouldn't crash or anything. Or is it just bad practice to do it this way?

Comment: So a downvote and a comment, but no explanation why it is wrong?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but as trudyscousin said on the other answer that got downvoted, it's probably because this is a kludge rather than a fix for the underlying problem, which is that the variable was incorrectly typed as `NSObject*`.

Comment: Also, if you are going to cast, it doesn't really matter at what point you do it as long as you're only sending messages both classes respond to (such as `isKindOfClass:`).

Comment: Thanks Chuck for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary* resp = [((NSArray *)response) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope it works

Comment: Can someone explain me why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but if anyone did, it's likely because your answer is like a plaster on a wound that still exists, which is `response` being an instance of `NSObject` when it should have been `id` instead.